# Match pattern of a list of words and highlight the found results

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, match, conditional-formatting

I want Excel to look up which row in column1 contains those strings in column2.
When found, highlight those rows in column1. Then I can group those rows together and use them for something else.
I have a big data set so I need this to be automated.

```
Column1                     Column2
Very long text 'UY58IOP'    UY58IOP
Very long text 'UY58IOP'    LDK09JY
Very long text 'LDK09JY'    TE89UTY
Very long text 'TE89UTY'
Very long text 'OO48TSI'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try selecting ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting - New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,8),7),B:B,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Fill, select your choice of highlighting, OK, OK.